# Matching regexp in SetEnvIf apache

Tags: regex, apache, header, content-disposition

I have googled a lot, tried different approaches, but failed. 
Please help.

What do I want to do:

Replace `Content-Disposition` header with value, supplied with a link.

Link:
http://x.x.x.x/download/d62519317661352416033f343ff871ff253caaf0/58920d09/7571578192jsdgsdg?as=transfer.avi

Part of my apache config file which deals with the header:

```
<Location /download/>
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*\?as\=(.*)\??.*$" FILENAME=$1
Header unset "Content-Disposition"
Header add "Content-Disposition" "attachment; filename=\"%{FILENAME}e\""
```

However, it seems that regex did not match and I receive (null) in the filename:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="(null)"
```

The interesting thing is that online regex matching tools show that expression is right. Also `$1` should match to Group1 match. 
[regexptool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgQ3v.jpg)

Comment: Ok, figured it out.
Below, anyone may find a piece of configuration which worked for me.

Comment: `<Location /download/>

        # Parses a query string (after "?") and puts everything found after "=as" into DOWNLOAD env variable
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)as=(.*)
        RewriteRule ^ - [E=DOWNLOAD:%1]
        Header set "Content-Disposition" "attachment; filename=\"%       {DOWNLOAD}e\"" env=DOWNLOAD`

Comment: Initial solution did not work because Apache removes everything after "?" in 'Request_URL" because it is against HTTP protocol to use "?" as a part of resource link.